# Elasticsearch integrations AD

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, active-directory, kibana

I did the elasticsearch Active Directory integration, and everything works except that now I can’t log in as a local user, maybe someone knows what the problem is?

before the integration was done, it was possible to log in as a local user, but now not